# Image out of the container

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
 <div class="container p0">
    <div class="col-md-12 p0">
        <div class="col-md-6 p0">
           <div class="imagen"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 p0">
           <div class="text-content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

I do not have a definite css yet, I still think how I can do this

How can I make the image full width inside a container, just like in the example using bootstrap, The black border is the bootstrap container

What I try to do is the content in a container and the image outside of that container,

[image]

Comment: can you update it on jsfiddle ? (and be careful to add the corresponding dependencies)

Comment: try this .imagen > img {max-width:100%}. hope this helps..

Comment: Please provide a demo, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just set these properties--

```
.imagen img{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: I think that's not possible, if it's inside a container or is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/9drawa3h/1/.

```
<div class="container p0">
    <div class="col-md-12 p0">
        <div class="col-md-6 p0">
            <div class="imagen"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 p0">
            <div class="text-content">
                <img src="http://a57.foxnews.com/images.foxnews.com/content/fox-news/tech/2013/04/13/how-to-do-free-online-background-check/_jcr_content/par/featured-media/media-1.img.jpg/876/493/1422493303787.jpg?ve=1&tl=1" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know you are looking for text-content in the second column, but I specified something else.

As I not sure whether you are going to use img tag ro background-image in the 1st column, so I have provided both.

1st Column with background-image and 2nd column with img tag.